# "Recent Achievements": bug with sites that have custom badges icons

Tags: bug, badges, achievements-dialog

Let's take Aviation and Stack Overflow for example. Aviation has custom icons for badges while Stack Overflow doesn't. Today I received a badge on Stack Overflow, but if accessing "Recent Achievements" when on Aviation then its custom icon is used even though the site's logo on the left shows the correct logo.

On Stack Overflow:

[image]

On Aviation:

[image]